# Issue with the ternary statement

Tags: coldfusion, conditional-operator

```
<cfscript>
    x = 100;
    y = 1;
    var i = len(x) ? ((y == 1) ? 'PD': 'PP') : 'PU'
    dump(i);
</cfscript>
```

problem is it is coming as `PD` while it should come as `PP`

If i am running in this `gist`, it works, only in my actual code it is behaving `odd`,

the values are not coming from anywhere else i double checked it

possibly if i write it in another way, that might fix it, any way i can do it

Comment: To my retired programmer's eye, it appears the answer is `PD` because y is equal to 1.  Why do you think it should be `PP`?

Comment: but in DB, the y is not 1 and there is len of x which is some numeric valuer, so it should not be PD, it should be PP, but not sure why it is pointing to PD

Comment: x is an integer not a string, and Len() returns the length of a string. In theory it should always evaluate x to 3 because it will convert 100 to a string first, so it will always evaluate to the first expression, which is itself another ternary expression, and since y is 1, the result will be it’s first expression, which is PD.

Comment: when in doubt use if/else blocks instead of ternary

Comment: can you help in this rewrite

Comment: Could you first translate your code to prose and explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `len()` of a number makes me nervous. Who knows what internal decimal it is using

Comment: `not sure why it is pointing to PD` Add some troubleshooting code to find out why  it's evaluating differently than you expect https://trycf.com/gist/e110d7d774463ae39d5c48cde196b8b2/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: ... and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary logic is essentially "if my condition is true, then do this, else do that.

```
<cfscript>
    x = 100;
    y = 1;
    var i = len(x) ? ((y == 1) ? 'PD': 'PP') : 'PU'
    dump(i);
</cfscript>
```

As written, what you have is:

"If there is a length of x, then ( if y is 1 then 'PD', else 'PP' ), else 'PU'.

Step 1: `len(x)` >>> x is the number 100, but is converted to the string "100", whose length is 3. But since ternary is a conditional, `len(x)` is `true`. So 'PU' can't be the answer.

Step 2: `y == 1` >>> another conditional. And since you've set `y` to `1`, then that is also `true`. So the answer will be the first part, or 'PD'.

Step 3: `i` is set to `'PD'`, as per the above ternary operations.

The answer you are getting is correct.

Comment: .. and if you're getting a different result in your local code, then it must be using different values than what you posted.